# How to correct error after upgrading to Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125)

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval

I recently upgraded to Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125) from the App Store and updated my apps to Swift 5. However, I am now getting an Invalid Binary through Apple Store Connect. Their response being:

> Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with a beta version of Xcode or >SDK. Apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the GM version >of Xcode 9 and the SDK for iOS 11, tvOS 11, watchOS 4, or macOS 10.13 >or later.

Has anyone experienced this issue and do you know how to correct it?

Comment: Asked 9 minutes from each other. .. was never shown a suggestion. Possible lag with stack overflow.